# Base class function accessing derived class member

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Below is an example of what I am trying to do. Basically, my `GetInt()` function is defined in the base class `A`, and my derived class `B` should also use the same definition. But the catch is that, when I access `GetInt()` from an object of class `B`, I want to return the derived class's member not the base's one. But the Output of below code gives:

```
Constructor A called
Constructor A called
Constructor B called
Object A: 10
Object B: 10
```

whereas I want it to be:

```
Constructor A called
Constructor A called
Constructor B called
Object A: 10
Object B: 5
```

My code:

```
class A{
        public:
                A(){
                        std::cout << "Constructor A called" << std::endl;
                        m_nA = 10;
                }
                int GetInt(){
                        return m_nA;
                }
        private:
                int m_nA;
};
class B : public A{
        public:
                B(){
                        std::cout << "Constructor B called" << std::endl;
                        m_nA = 5;
                }
        private:
                int m_nA;
};

int main(){
        A ObjA; B ObjB;
        std::cout << "Object A: " << ObjA.A::GetInt() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Object B: " << ObjB.B::GetInt() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private:
            int m_nA;
```

Change the above in base class "A" to "protected".
Don't define the member "m_nA" in "class B".
Thats it! you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `A::GetInt()`, and that will always return `A::m_nA`.

Unless you can change the name of `B::m_nA`, the only thing you can do it to use virtual functions :

```
class A{
        public:
                A() : m_nA(10){
                        std::cout << "Constructor A called" << std::endl;
                }
                virtual int GetInt(){
                        return m_nA;
                }
        private:
                int m_nA;
};
class B : public A{
        public:
                B() : A(), m_nA(5){
                        std::cout << "Constructor B called" << std::endl;
                }
                virtual int GetInt(){
                        return m_nA;
                }
        private:
                int m_nA;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Virtual function is a good option but You can also use this code.

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
        std::cout << "Constructor A called" << std::endl;
        m_nA = 10;
    }

    int GetInt(){
        return m_nA;
    }

protected:
    int m_nA;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B(){
        std::cout << "Constructor B called" << std::endl;
        m_nA = 5;
    }
};
```

In this case when we call the Class B constructor it first call the class A constructor so initialize m_nA with 10. Then in body of class B constructor it override m_nA value with 5. So in this case always gives the correct result as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `GetInt()` virtual and override it in the sub class:

```
class A{
    public:
        A(){
            std::cout << "Constructor A called" << std::endl;
            m_nA = 10;
        }

        virtual int GetInt(){
            return m_nA;
        }

    private:
        int m_nA;
};

class B : public A{
    public:
        B(){
            std::cout << "Constructor B called" << std::endl;
            m_nA = 5;
        }

        virtual int GetInt(){
            return m_nA;
        }

    private:
        int m_nA;
};
```

```
Constructor A called
Constructor A called
Constructor B called
Object A: 10
Object B: 5
```

Since you are explicitly calling the method by specifying the type `A::` and `B::`, you do not necessarily need to make it virtual - but you would then not be able to call `B::GetInt()` through a pointer or reference to `A` (no late binding):

```
A& ObjAb = ObjB;
std::cout << "Object B through A&: " << ObjAb.GetInt() << std::endl;
```

With virtual method:

```
Object B through A&: 5
```

With non-virtual method:

```
Object B through A&: 10
```

Comment: no need to declare GetInt as virtual again in class B, once virtual in base class, teh function is overridable in its subclasses

Comment: @DebasishJana true, but I prefer to repeat it in the sub class to make it visible that this is a virtual method. In particular, `virtual` would not be necessary at all since OP does not call it through a pointer or reference

Comment: It doesn't even have to be virtual in the base-class, if he's intending on only using it like this.